# Bring data from another page with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to bring the data from Details.cshtml to show in index.cshtml when i press a button in "with ajax but i don't figured out how to do it. I'm already try funcion load.`enter code here`

```
...       <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ContactId">Edit</a> |
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ContactId">Details</a>|
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ContactId">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

The data i want to show in the other page is from this form.

```
    @model Trabalho.Models.Contact

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

    <h4>Contact</h4>

    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ContactNumber)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ContactNumber)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Country)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Country)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>
    </dl>
<div>
    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.ContactId">Edit</a> |
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Someone can help?

Comment: where is you javascript?

Comment: I was using this <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
 $('#mydiv').load('somepage.htm');
});

but without sucess

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: no, even running the code, just don't show the data I want it to show

Comment: where is the `#mydiv'` element?

Comment: I try puting in Details table, to get the information from form, but did't work

Comment: where is your ajax code?

Comment: is there any xhr request in your network tab when you refresh the page?